# How to begin creating Linq-To-Repository to HttpRequest framework

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2, query-expressions

As an example I have a simple web api which has has a single controller called ParentsController it's a standard WebAPi2 ApiController. It is boiler plate.

On the client side I have created an Repository Base class and based on that I have a ParentRepository class.

ApiRequester:

```
    public class ApiRequester
{
    readonly Uri _apiServiceBaseAddress;
    readonly String _apiControllerPath;
    readonly Guid _apiKey;

    public ApiRequester(string apiServiceBaseAddress, string apiControllerPath, Guid apiKey)
    {
        _apiServiceBaseAddress = new Uri(apiServiceBaseAddress);
        _apiControllerPath = apiControllerPath;
        _apiKey = apiKey;
    }
    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string queryParameters)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _apiServiceBaseAddress })
        {
            //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-APIKey", _apiKey.ToString());

            var response = await client.GetAsync(_apiControllerPath + queryParameters);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();

            return result;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> Post<T>(string queryParameters, T entity)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _apiServiceBaseAddress })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-APIKey", _apiKey.ToString());
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(_apiControllerPath + queryParameters, entity);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> Put<T>(string queryParameters, T entity)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _apiServiceBaseAddress })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-APIKey", _apiKey.ToString());
            var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync<T>(_apiControllerPath + queryParameters, entity);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();

            return result;
        }
    }

    public async Task Delete(string queryParameters)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _apiServiceBaseAddress })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-APIKey", _apiKey.ToString());

            var response = await client.DeleteAsync(_apiControllerPath + queryParameters);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

RepositoryBase:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    readonly ApiRequester _requester;

    protected RepositoryBase(string apiBaseUri, string controllerPath, Guid apiKey)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiBaseUri))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("apiBaseUri");

        if (apiKey.Equals(default(Guid)))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("apiKey");

        _requester = new ApiRequester(apiBaseUri, controllerPath, apiKey);
    }
    public virtual Task<ICollection<T>> GetAsync(string queryParameters)
    {
        return _requester.Get<ICollection<T>>(queryParameters);
    }

    public virtual Task<T> PostAsync(string queryParameters, T entity)
    {
        return _requester.Post<T>(queryParameters, entity);
    }

    public virtual Task<T> PutAsync(string queryParameters, T entity)
    {
        return _requester.Put<T>(queryParameters, entity);
    }
    public virtual Task DeleteAsync(string queryParameters)
    {
        return _requester.Delete(queryParameters);
    }
}
```

ParentRepository:

```
    public class ParentRepository : RepositoryBase<Parent>
{
    public ChannelRepository(string apiBaseUri, string controllerPath, Guid apiKey)
        : base(apiBaseUri, controllerPath, apiKey)
    { }
}
```

Thus consumers of the client can make a call to get a list of parent from the API thus:

```
pRepo = new ParentRepository();
var parents = await pRepo.GetAsync();

// Do something with parent collection.
```

The Parent entity looks like this:

```
public class Parent : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

// Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to allow on my repository methods is something similar to the following:

```
pRepo = new ParentRepository();
var parents = await pRepo.GetAsync().Where(p => p.Name == "aName").Include(p => p.Children);
```

And here is where I am stuck.

How do I intercept this in my GetAsync() method such that I can build my http request?

To get the 'Where' clause  do I create an Extension method?
something like:

```
public static ICollection<TEntity> Where(this ICollection<TEntity> source, Func<TEntity> , bool> predicate)
{
// Do something or not?
}
```

but then what?

And for the 'Include' part,  What do I need here, perhaps something from System.Reflection to get the Child collection property name?

Again how do I intercept the inference in my GetAsync() method?

I understand there are easier ways to do what I want with overloaded methods perhaps, but I like the idea of the creating a linq like approach.

EDIT:

For clarity what I want and I think I need to use expression trees (not sure how yet) to convert my linq expression to a web uri:

so in my client I write: `var parents = await pRepo.GetAsync().Where(p => p.Name == "aName").Include(p => p.Children);`

and that expression gets converted to something like:

```
GET /api/parents/?name=aName&IncludeChildren=true
```

The client can then perform the Get request.  Note this should be something I can use in any client I build targeting any type of web based API does not necessarily need to be WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

In my (limited) experience, the Web API Controllers have the optional parameters for things like filtering and sorting, and then translate these into linq-like requests to Repository classes in a data access layer. None of which resides on the client, which is making requests to the Web API controller using standard HTTP conventions in the query string such as:

```
GET /api/parent?minimumId=5&maximumId=20&orderBy=Name
```

The optional query string parameters could be converted into either Linq or [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) to query some sort of IQueryable provided by the underlying DAL.

You probably won't see linq-like behavior on the requests to the Web API controllers very often since the controllers are HTTP-oriented in nature, and tend towards HTTP-like behavior instead.

If you really want to wrap the calls to the Web API controllers in Linq-like syntax, I would look into converting your data (Funcs/Expressions/Strings/etc) into Linq queries using [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) since it at least lets you avoid fussing with the reflection yourself.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not specific I will edit it.
What I want to do and with some research I think I need to work with Expression Trees - still not sure how though.
I want to convert:
pRepo = new ParentRepository();
var parents = await pRepo.GetAsync().Where(p => p.Name == "aName").Include(p => p.Children); to /api/parent?name=aName&IncludeChildren=true

Comment: This is a bit clearer. I'll try to edit my answer later today with at least a partial solution to the intended question.